# Why are logs sometimes dated and sometimes supplemental?

Tags: star-trek

There doesn't seem to be any pattern to when it's "Captain's Log, StarDate xxx' and 'Captain's Log, Supplemental".  Is there any?

Comment: It always seemed to me that each "day" had a new Captain's Log; if there was something else to add later in the day, that's a supplemental

Comment: A "supplemental" log is something that gets tacked onto an existing logfile.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**"Captain's Log, Stardate XXXX"** is the beginning point of an entry, and generally occurs at the start of a new episode or adventure.

**"Captain's Log, Supplemental"** is a later addition to an existing log entry, generally made mid-way through an episode or adventure.  The idea is that the Captain came back later and tacked-on another bit of important information to an entry they had made earlier.

In my experience, the pattern holds up quite well:

- In-universe, each new log entry is for a major event or mission, and supplementary material is added during the mission or after the mission is completed.
- Out-of-universe, each new log entry begins a new episode, and supplementary entries are usually a way of either catching up viewers who may be starting the episode mid-way through, or quickly establishing events that have occurred off-screen during a commercial break.

Comment: It also happens from time to time that an episode opens with a supplemental. That's generally when the episode starts in the middle of an mission or adventure, meaning this general idea still holds up.